# Access the Visual Viewport API from scala.js

Tags: scala, api, viewport, scala.js

does anyone know how I can access the visual viewport API in scala.js? When I try to access the `visualViewport` object on the `dom.window` object it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it out how to do it actually. By adding an asInstanceOf before calling the visualViewport variable it can be made accessible. Maybe someone finds that helpful.

`val visualViewport = dom.window.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].visualViewport`